# I have a problem with the button on click event when the button resides in a child grid

Tags: xml, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

I have wrote some xml code where I have 2 grids, one being the main grid residing in a stack layout, the other a child grid residing in a stack layout within the first grid.

The problem is...when I place the child grid within another, the buttons and the label that sit within the child grid do not work any more.

Can anyone please tell me the reason and maybe guid me to a better solution?
here i my code...

```
<StackLayout Padding="{StaticResource PagePadding}" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Spacing="{StaticResource PageSpacing}">
        <Grid x:Name="controlGrid"
                RowDefinitions="{StaticResource MainRowStyle}" 
                ColumnDefinitions="{StaticResource MainColumnStyle}" 
                Style="{StaticResource MainGridStyle}"
                StyleClass="MainGrid">
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <controls:PickerClass HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    HeightRequest="40" 
                    Image="DownArrow.png"
                    Title="Style?"
                    x:Name="StylePicker"
                    PropertyChanged="SetDefaultSyle"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding BasicStyles}" 
                    ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding StyleName}"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStyle}">
                </controls:PickerClass>
            </StackLayout>
            <!--Just some other labels and buttons, removed to keep example smaller now the second grid-->
            <StackLayout Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Grid.RowSpan="1">
                <Grid RowDefinitions="{StaticResource GridRowLayout3}" 
                      ColumnDefinitions="{StaticResource GridColumnLayout3}" >
                    <Entry x:Name="txtLocation" Text="{Binding GetFolder}"
                        Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
                        Style="{StaticResource MainEntryStyle}"
                        Placeholder="Name"/>
                    <Button x:Name="btnSave" Text="Save Folder"
                        Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
                        Style="{StaticResource MainButtonStyle}"
                        IsEnabled="{Binding IsNotBusy}"
                        Command="{Binding SaveContactCommand}"/>
                    <Button x:Name="btnCreate" Text="Create"
                        Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
                        Style="{StaticResource MainButtonStyle}"
                        IsEnabled="{Binding IsNotBusy}"
                        Command="{Binding CreateDir}"/>
                    <Button x:Name="btnGrid" Text="App"
                        Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
                        Style="{StaticResource MainButtonStyle}"
                        Clicked="Get_Grid"/>
                </Grid>
            </StackLayout>
            <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="1" Color="red"/>
            <StackLayout Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Grid.RowSpan="2" >
                <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" x:Name="lblNetStatus"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
```

Comment: Where did you defined the rows and coloums?

Comment: They are defined in my resources stylesheet.

Comment: @AndroDevil, ok I assume that was a hint...Hit the ball on the head, I spanned the stackLayout over 3 rows and that solved it :-) Thnx..`<!--Just some other labels and buttons, removed to keep example smaller now the second grid-->
            <StackLayout Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Grid.RowSpan="3">`

Comment: Happy coding .

Comment: Thank you, I am learning a lot from all of you guys :-)